What is poisoning?
I am once again asking for an analysis of an ugo lord video.
In the video a prankster woman puts very spicy hot sauce on her boyfriends food without his knowledge.  Ugo states that it is "100% illegal" and that "most jurisdictions would consider it to be poison".
Most of the laws on poisoning I've found stipulate that poisoning is intentionally adding an ingredient that is known to cause injury.  Hot sauce doesn't actually damage the body, instead it just tricks your body into thinking it's being damaged however it does objectively hurt which I'm sure counts as injury.
I have two questions related to this:

The line about being 100% illegal and potentially even poisoning seems to indicate that even if not poisoning it would fall into some other crime.  What crime would it be if not poisoning?  Assault and/or battery?
In either event, where is the line?  When I was younger my grandmother used to always sneak ingredients I don't like into the food in order to trick me into eating them.  Could putting mayonnaise on my sandwich intentionally against my wishes be considered "injury"?  If I invite some friends over and make a spicy dish could I be liable?  People handle spice differently so even if I warn that a food is "mildly spicy" it could still have a very harsh reaction to someone with a low spice tolerance.  There are also a lot of variables in spice, especially when fresh peppers are used.  The pepper used in one dish could be a 4/10 while the pepper in the next dish could be an 8/10 even though it's the same species.  So even though spicy food objectively "hurts" the amount of pain is very much subjective.


Broadly in the US this can be considered Tampering with Food/consumer product, battery and or assault, and a bevy of other crimes.
NY law § 145.14 Criminal tampering in the third degree.
A person is guilty of criminal tampering in the third degree when,
having no right to do so nor any reasonable ground to believe that he
has such right, he tampers with property of another person with intent
to cause substantial inconvenience to such person or to a third person.
Harassment can be consided (NY harassment law is like common description of assault).
You don't need to injure someone to be guilty, making someone fear of injury would be enough. Other states make "annoying" someone a crime, or unwanted touching. Even putting them just at risk of adverse reactions is enough. And their subjective belief is enough, unless outrageously unreasonable (football player taking a dive 5 seconds after being poked)
A kid was charged with 5 counts of battery, 3 of which for people that just smelled the really strong hot sauce and had negative effects from it.
https://www.cbsnews.com/chicago/news/teen-charged-after-hot-sauce-prank-at-highland-park-high-school/
With your parents or grandmother in loco parentis, the lack of injury would make it not a crime, they have control over you and no intent to harm.
With a stranger putting Mayo when you said no mayo, unless you can prove malicious intent (or they admit it like an idiot) it would not be criminal.
With you warning your guests that it's spicy, again with no intent to injure it wouldn't be criminal. If unreasonably injurious it could be a tort, but since you warned them it was spicy in some way, they assumed a level of risk (like a spectator at a baseball game).

Thanks.  In the video it looks like the woman actually purchased the food as a gift for her boyfriend so I wonder if that would still be eligible for the criminal tampering since it wasn't technically his property.

@jesse_b she gave that property to another person making it there property. That could be a contentious part of the case, but consider how often people get in trouble for booby trapping their own lunch because someone is stealing in the office fridge.

True but she tampered with it before it was gifted.  Not trying to be argumentative just seems like that could make things different.

canada
In Canada, the offence that could potentially cover the action in the hypothetical is called "Administering a noxious thing" found at s. 245 of the Criminal Code:

245 (1) Every person who administers or causes to be administered to any other person or causes any other person to take poison or any other destructive or noxious thing is guilty
(a) of an indictable offence and liable to imprisonment for a term of not more than 14 years, if they did so with intent to endanger the life of or to cause bodily harm to that person; or
(b) of an indictable offence and liable to imprisonment for a term of not more than two years or of an offence punishable on summary conviction, if they did so with intent to aggrieve or annoy that person.

The statutory description of this offence avoids the need to define "poison" as separate from "noxious thing."
As for what makes something a "noxious thing," that depends on the circumstances (see R. v H.P., 2016 ONSC 2342, at para 139, quoting R. v. Burkholder, 1977 ALTASCAD 8, 2 A.R. 119):

a substance is a noxious thing if, in the light of all of the circumstances attendant upon its administration, it is capable of effecting, or in the normal course of events will effect, a consequence defined in s.229 [what is now s. 245, ie. the consequences of endangering the life of, causing bodily harm to, aggrieving or annoying that person]. Circumstances that may arise and which have to be considered in determining whether a substance is noxious include its inherent characteristics, the quantity administered, and the manner in which it is administered.  Substances which may be innocuous, such as water to drink or an aspirin for a headache, may be found to be a noxious substance in some circumstances; for example, if water is injected into the body of a person by means of a hypodermic syringe or an excessive quantity of aspirin is administered to a person

A crucial limitation to this offence is that the prosecution must prove that the person administering the substance did so either:

with intent to endanger the life of or to cause bodily harm to that person; or
with intent to aggrieve or annoy that person.


england-and-wales
Generally, to administer any poison or other destructive or noxious thing with intent to endanger life or inflict grievous bodily harm (GBH), or to injure, aggrieve or annoy any other person, contrary to the Offences against the Person Act 1861:

23 Maliciously administering poison, &c. so as to endanger life or inflict grievous bodily harm.
Whosoever shall unlawfully and maliciously administer to or cause to be administered to or taken by any other person any poison or other destructive or noxious thing, so as thereby to endanger the life of such person, or so as thereby to inflict upon such person any grievous bodily harm, shall be guilty of felony, and being convicted thereof shall be liable ...


24 Maliciously administering poison, &c. with intent to injure, aggrieve, or annoy any other person.
Whosoever shall unlawfully and maliciously administer to or cause to be administered to or taken by any other person any poison or other destructive or noxious thing, with intent to injure, aggrieve, or annoy such person, shall be guilty of a misdemeanor, and being convicted thereof shall be liable ...

Crown Prosecution Service guidance:

R v Veysey [2019] EWCA Crim 1332 provides guidance on charging and on what may amount to a “noxious substance”. Where an issue arises as to whether a substance is a noxious thing for the purpose of section 24 of the 1861 Act, it will be for the judge to rule as a matter of law whether the substance concerned, in the quantity and manner in which it is shown by the evidence to have been administered, could properly be found by the jury to be injurious, hurtful, harmful or unwholesome. If it can be properly so regarded, it will be a matter for the jury whether they are satisfied that it was a noxious thing within that definition. In Veysey’s case, the judge below had been entitled to find that a cupful of human urine, from an unknown source, thrown at the face of a victim was capable of being regarded as noxious. Actual or potential injury / harm is likely to indicate that a substance is noxious but that is not an exhaustive definition and it may extent on the facts to any hurtful or unwholesome substance.

In a case such as 'spiking' someone's drink to have sex with them, section 61 Sexual Offences Act 2003 makes it an offence to intentionally administer a substance to, or cause a substance to be taken by, another person (B) knowing that B does not consent, and with the intention of stupefying or overpowering B, so as to enable any person to engage in a sexual activity that involves B.

I think there's also the possibility for being reckless when there's a known or perceived risk https://www.lawteacher.net/lectures/criminal-law/committing-an-offence/mens-rea/#recklessness
